# When reversing a string converted from an int, the ending 0's are not being printed

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
num = 123401000

def reverse_int(num):
    sign = 1

    if num > 0:
        sign = 1
    else:
        sign = -1

    print(sign)
    tmp = abs(num)
    print(tmp)

    return int(str(tmp)[::-1]) * sign

print(reverse_int(num))
```

The purpose of this code is to print out the reverse of `num`, but this code prints out `104321`. Can anyone tell me why the last zeros are not being captured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros were captured. But when you converted it back to an `int` at the end, numerically there is no difference between `000104321` and `104321`, and `int`s have only one native representation (`001` and `1` are not going to be stored differently to keep the `0`s). If you need to preserve those zeroes, you can't convert back to `int`, you have to leave it as a `str`.

An approach you could take would be to have `sign` store the prefix string, not a number, making your code:

```
def reverse_int(num):
    if num >= 0:
        sign = ''  # No sign to add
    else:
        sign = '-'  # Keep negative sign

    print(sign)
    tmp = abs(num)
    print(tmp)

    return sign + str(tmp)[::-1]
```

Comment: You don't have to keep the number as a string. You just have to print it correctly. The leasing zeros' count is encoded in the length of the string, so there's any number of ways of printing it correctly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: True. But it's easier to return the string form and let them convert back to `int` if they so choose (they can always wrap the call itself in `int()` if they don't need the string form at all). Your solution is workable, but it's a very strange API, given it's trying to serve the dual purpose of returning the numeric value, but also, here's the width to use if you want to print it with matching width.

Answer (score 0):

An integer naturally does not retain leading zeros in the way that a string does. 0001 is just 1. During the forward conversion, this is a good thing: `123401000` becomes `'123401000'`, not `'0000123401000'`.

Putting it another way, there are an infinite number of leading zeros in any integer. There is no particular reason for Python to print any particular number of them (how does it know if you mean 001, 01 or 1?), so by default, leading zeros are not printed.

You have access to the correct number of leading zeros, so there's nothing stopping you from printing them correctly. You certainly don't need to return your number as a string, just keep track of the *length* of your intermediate string. Have your function return both the reversed integer and the desired print width:

```
def reverse_int(num):
    sign = 1 if num >= 0 else -1
    tmp = num * sign
    string = str(tmp)
    width = len(string) + (sign == -1)
    return int(string[::-1]) * sign, width
```

Now, using the correct format specifier, you can print your leading zeros:

```
num = 123401000
rev, width = reverse_int(num)
print(f'{rev:0{width}d}')
```

You could make this even more concise with the older `format` function:

```
print('{:0{}d}'.format(*reverse_int(num)))
```

You can even use the really old-school string interpolation operator:

```
print('%0*d' % (width, rev))
```